# Found Unusual and Unknown Name ultimoUsuario in Cookies

Tags: session, cookies

On going through the Cookies of my PHP project created using `session_start();`, I have found this unusual and unknown name of `ultimoUsuario`. I am not sure what this is and did google it but it referred to nothing related with MySQL or PHP. Here is the screenshot of Chrome Settings.

[image]

Please advise what this is?

Comment: Doesn't it mean "last user" in spanish ?

Comment: I am not sure sir. After several times I have deleted all cookies and started the session, that Name never came up again. So I was inquisitive about what that is and Google too didn't show anything on it. But sir, my question remains, what it is?